# Eclipse CDT build C project with gcc not g++

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc

I installed the Mingw32 base to get access to the `gcc` command (Added also `/bin` folder to `PATH`).
Moreover I installed Eclipse CDT Mars, created a C project and selected the MingW32 toolchain.
Now if I try to compile a simple program written in `main.c`, Eclipse tells me it couldn't find `g++`.
I know Eclipse can't find `g++` because I only installed the MingW32 base, so `gcc` is the only one available.
But I also created only a C project not a C++ project.

So why eclipse try to compile with `g++` not `gcc`?
How I can change this?